# How does Rosuvastatin 5 S-lactone form in human body?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, drugs, pharmacology

I've searched lots of free resources online but cannot find the answer.
[image]

the top compound is Rosuvastatin.
Some websites say it is metabolized by the enzyme CYP2C9, 
but I can't figure out how a CYP450 mediated reaction will produce Rosuvastatin 5 S-lactone. And I tried thinking about an intramolecular esterification, but it does not look like the answer. Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: It seems like you have drawn two excess double bonds. Maybe this is the source of your confusion. Besides this intramolecular esterification is ok.

Comment: Oh I compared the picture of pubchem and drugbank, I found that they are different. If pubchem is right then it can be form through intramolecular esterification but I'm not sure. DB: https://www.drugbank.ca/reactions/2249 PC: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/66631534#section=2D-Structure

Answer (score 6):

Rosuvastatin is metabolized to a limited extent by CYP2C9 to form an N-desmethyl metabolite and the other metabolite is the **rosuvastatin lactone**.

[image]

*The acid moeity (highlighted part) is likely to undergo glucuronidation first and subsequently lactonisation to form the rosuvastatin lactone*

Unlike other statins, rosuvastatin undergoes relatively little metabolism by hepatic CYPs with no significant involvement of CYP3A4.

> The metabolism of statins is complex, involving the inter-conversion
>   of acid/lactone by various pathways. The acid forms are converted to
>   the corresponding lactones via a **glucuronide intermediate**.

Here is the proposed, generalised metabolic pathway of statins. The acid forms of statins are converted to the corresponding lactones via a glucuronide intermediate via **an elimination reaction.**

[image]

*Sidenote for some statins: (After metabolism by CYP3A4 some of the resulting lactone metabolites are converted to the corresponding acid forms:*

References

- Focus on Statin research. B. A. Wong: Drug Metabolism and Transporter profiles of Statins.
- Foye’s Principles of Medicinal Chemistry 7th ed

Comment: Really appreciate your detailed answer!